# OSCache jsp tag to first return from cache and then clear

Tags: java, jsp-tags, oscache

I am using OSCache on my jsps with tags. To improve performance, I am caching some of the jsp using the oscache jsp tags.

I would like the cache to always return the cached result and then rebuild the cahce. This way my users do not wait for the cache to be re-built. After returning the cached result, a flush can occur.

Anyone has an idea how to implement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I dropped OSCache completely as it is not supported anymore. I am now using EHCache which works great!

Assaf